# Why is my React Websocket stuck on connecting until component renders?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

In my React component, I have a Websocket that is stuck in a connecting state until my component renders. The code looks as follows:

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [websocket, setWebsocket] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const newWebsocket = new WebSocket(ENDPOINT);
        newWebsocket.onopen = () => console.log('hello there!');
        setWebsocket(newWebsocket);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`readState: ${ws?.readyState}`);
    }, [ws?.readyState]};

    const onRender = useCallback(() => {
        if (websocket === null) {
            return;
        }
        websocket.onmessage = () => console.log('received a message!');
    }, [websocket]);

    return (
        (websocket !== null) 
            ? <ChildComponent onRender={onRender} />
            : <div> No Websocket </div>
    );
}
```

`hello there!` prints, which shows the WebSocket connection is open, but the `useEffect` logging readyState only prints `CONNECTING`.

Does `websocket.onmessage` have to be defined before the websocket can transition from connecting to open? Or is there some other issue going on?

I expect the websocket to transition from connecting to open without needing `ChildComponent` to first render. However, what happens now is that I need to define something like

```
return (
    (websocket?.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING || websocket?.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN)
        ? <ChildComponent onRender={onRender} />
        : <div> No WebSocket </div>
);
```

for the websocket to go from connecting to open. What I'd like to do is define something like this

```
return (
    (websocket?.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN)
        ? <ChildComponent onRender={onRender} />
        : <div> No WebSocket </div>
);
```

Comment: `useEffect` doesn't listen for variable change. `useEffect` runs the code if a variable changed, but you have to trigger rerender to activate that check. You are calling `setWebsocket`, you would need to do that every time `ws?.readyState` changes

Comment: Try `const [, rerender] = useReducer(x => !x, false);` and then `newWebsocket.onopen = () => rerender();`

Comment: thanks Konrad! per `ws?.readyState`, I intended to write `websocket?.readyState`. I realized later my error is that the state variable `websocket` isn't changing, just the property `readyState`. So when `websocket?.readyState` changes, this won't trigger a re render. I also like the `rerender()` idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because updates to `websocket.readyState` will not trigger a re-render. While updates to the state variable `websocket` will trigger an update, updates of the properties of `websocket` will not. If you want the screen to update, you can do something like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [websocket, setWebsocket] = useState(null);
    const [readyState, setReadyState] = useState(WebSocket.CLOSED);

    useEffect(() => {
        const newWebsocket = new WebSocket(ENDPOINT);
        setReadyState(WebSocket.CONNECTING);
        newWebsocket.onopen = () => setReadyState(WebSocket.OPEN);
        newWebsocket.onclose = () => setReadyState(WebSocket.CLOSED);
        setWebsocket(newWebsocket);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`readyState: ${readyState}`);
    }, [readyState]};

    const onRender = useCallback(() => {
        if (websocket === null) {
            return;
        }
        websocket.onmessage = () => console.log('received a message!');
    }, [websocket]);

    return (
        (readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) 
            ? <ChildComponent onRender={onRender} />
            : <div> No Websocket </div>
    );
}
```